# Is possible to refresh ViewModel property in ZUL without command?

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I'm right now working in a project with ZK Framework with Java.

I want to refresh some properties in ViewModel directly in my zul file, for example:

```
<toolbarbutton disabled="@load(vm.myModel.isSelectionEmpty())" id="newAdvertising" image="/resources/images/add.png" onClick="@command('openAdvertisingPopup', mode='new')" />
```

I want this button to be enabled if there is some items selected in "myModel" property.

However, I don't want to create a command in my ViewModel only to refresh this property when something is selected. Is possible in ZK to do this directly in the zul file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EL expressions](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/EL_Expressions/Operators) and in this particular case the operator **empty**:

```
<toolbarbutton disabled="@load(empty vm.sel)" />
```

where vm.sel is hypothetically used like this:

```
<listbox emptyMessage="This list is empty" selectedItems="@bind(vm.sel)"
         checkmark="true" multiple="true" model="@load(vm.model)">
```

Comment: Where is `NotifyChange` logic here?

Comment: In my opinion the request was about  to disable a button if there weren't items selected and do this directly in zul WITHOUT implements a command and without the @NotifyChange. Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Let us suppose Page loaded first time that time it will be disable according to your logic,if someone selected any item how you enable it ?

Comment: @barracus That's it, but not only in first load in zul page, every time the user change the selection in 'sel'.
And Subodh Joshi, yeah, that's the problem. How is zul notified when the selection changes without a NotifyChange?

Comment: I don't get something. I use in my project the code I posted and it works fine. Once getters and setters for model al sel are properly implemented, I don't need notifychange in viewmodel. You need notifychange only wher in viewmodel you edit some values visualized in view. In my post, I edit vm.sel in view, without calling @Command which modify model, sel, etc.

Comment: I think your example is working maybe because you are using 'selectedItems' atributte with another property called 'vm.sel' .
In fact, I think you don't need this vm.sel in your ViewModel, because you can do model.getSelection() and retrieve the selected items.

I tried using @load(empty vm.myModel.selection) but it doesn't work either. So I think I won't be able to do this without a 'vm.sel' property maybe?